# Rerun method as soon as it has finished

Tags: c#, windows-services

Right now I'm using a timer to trigger my method. But how can I make the service run my method as soon as it has finished?

```
private Timer timer;

    public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomething();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 60000;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
```

Comment: @Habib Did you read my question? I don't want to use timer. I would like to rerun SomeThing() as soon as it has finished

Comment: oh I missed that part. Call your method from *inside*, your method to make it recursive. Not really sure if it would be a good approach. Also make sure you have some condition before calling your method recursively, otherwise you will end up with StackOverflow exception.

Comment: As worded, OP wanted to know how to execute the method again "as soon as it was finished." You are right that if the method only does something like Console.WriteLine("Boo!"), it will not be a very useful program as is.

Comment: When I make my method recursive I get Error 1053 when starting my service...But the process is started

Comment: I know this sounds flippant, but if you want to run DoSomething() again after it finishes, just call it again no?

Comment: Ah, Ok, error 1503 is specific to a Windows Service when the OnStart method doesn't execute within a certain timeframe. Updated the answer to address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the timer and use recursion:

```
public Service()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DoSomething();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
  // some code that takes a while to execute

  // make recursive call to self
  DoSomething();
}
```

**EDIT** The answer as accepted won't work in the context of a service (actually, it will execute, but the service itself will be forever stuck in 'Starting' status, and will generate a 1503 error).

Here is the full code for a service that will continuously execute a method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;

namespace recursion
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        System.Threading.Thread thread;

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\Foo.txt", "Starting at: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
            thread = new System.Threading.Thread(DoSomething);
            thread.Name = "Worker Thread";
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void DoSomething() {
            while (true)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\Foo.txt", "The Time is now: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

@cslecours you were wrong that it would cause a StackOverflow, but you were right in that causing the OnStart method not to exit would cause and error for a Windows service.

Comment: The inventors of many programming languages thought so. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z3dk2cc3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Do not do this, it will lead to a `StackOverflowException` as you never return from the function.

Comment: Your example and mine differ only in that you start a new thread to continuously run the method. If all he wants to do is run the method, and keep running it after it finishes (as he stated in his question), either will work perfectly fine. Are you suggesting that recursion - a basic staple of virtually every modern programming language - is dangerous and not to be used?

Comment: @GojiraDeMonstah Recursion is fine if it isn't infinite. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Infinite_recursion

In your case StackOverflow will happen eventually. Try it with a faster DoSomething that contains a Console.WriteLine call and a call to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Thread and an infinite while loop.

```
private void Start()
{
   while(true)
       DoSomething();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Start());
}
```

Comment: The problem with this (did I found out) is that I never get out of OnStart, and theres why I cant start the service i windows GUI